# Basic iPhone pasteboard usage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, copy-paste, uipasteboard

I'm trying to put some plain text in the iPhone Pasteboard. The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
UIPasteboard *pboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *value = @"test";
[pboard setValue: value forPasteboardType: @"public.plain-text"];
```

I'm guessing the problem is in the PasteBoard type argument. Passing `@"public.plain-text"` nothing happens. Passing `kUTTypePlainText` the compiler complains about incompatible pointer type, but doesn't crash, and nothing happens either. Using `kUTTypePlainText` also seems to require linking with `MobileCoreServices`, which is not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Can I ask why you are doing this instead of using the -[UIPasteboard setString:] method? Also, what do you mean by "nothing happens?" What were you expecting to happen exactly? How are you determining this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Responding to the comments and my own question:

- Setting the `pasteboard` string property works.
- Using `setValue:forPasteboardType:` also works if I use `kUTTypeUTF8PlainText` instead of `kUTTypePlainText` for the pasteboard type.

I had not noticed the string property because I went directly to the **"Getting and Setting Single Pasteboard Items"** tasks section.

The way I was testing was by clicking in a text field and see if the paste pop-up would appear.

I still am not sure where in the docs the UTT types are explained for the iPhone, including where to get them (Framework, `#include` files), it seems that the "Uniform Type Identifiers Overview" doc is still geared toward Mac OS. Since the constants gave me a type mismatch warning I thought I was doing something wrong, that's why I first tried using an `NSString` literal.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with being geared towards Mac OS X, as I explained, you just need to cast the string. The constants are declared as CFStringRef, which is tollfree bridged with NSString. Just do: (NSString *)kUTTypePlainText

Answer (score 19):

Use this header to get the value for kUTTypeUTF8PlainText;

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

You'll need to have the MobileCoreServices framework available.

Comment: The implementation just to make it crystal clear: `[pboard setValue:value forPasteboardType:(NSString*)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my experiments with pasting text onto the pasteboard. I'm using a button to add the text programatically.

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

- (IBAction)setPasteboardText:(id)sender
{
    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *text = @"東京京都大阪";

    // Works, but generates an incompatible pointer warning
    [pb setValue:text forPasteboardType:kUTTypeText];

    // Puts generic item (not text type), can't be pasted into a text field
    [pb setValue:text forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypeItem];

    // Works, even with non-ASCII text
    // I would say this is the best way to do it with unknown text
    [pb setValue:text forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypeText];

    // Works without warning
    // This would be my preferred method with UTF-8 text
    [pb setValue:text forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];

    // Works without warning, even with Japanese characters
    [pb setValue:text forPasteboardType:@"public.plain-text"];

    // Works without warning, even with Japanese characters
    [pb setValue:text forPasteboardType:@"public.text"];

    // Check contents and content type of pasteboard
    NSLog(@"%@", [pb items]);
}
```

I pasted the contents into a text field to check, and changed the text contents each time to make sure it wasn't just re-using the previous paste.

Comment: what should i have to do if i want to paste an image?